# Recurrence relation to calculate the number of strings of $n$ characters that don't have consecutive vowels.

Tags: recurrence-relations

How can I find a recurrence relation to calculate the number of strings of $n$ characters (english alphabet, lowercase) that don't have consecutive vowels.

It's clear that for $n = 1$ the result is $26$, but, then what? Just hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call such sequences **good**. Let $a_n$ be the number of good $n$-sequences that end in a vowel, and $b_n$ the number of good $n$-sequences that end in a consonant.
Then
$$a_{n+1}=5b_n$$

$$b_{n+1}=21(a_n+b_n).$$

From this one can derive a recurrence relation for the number $x_n$ of $n$-sequences that do not have $2$ consecutive vowels. As per request, we leave the details to you.