# Recurrence for number of strings of length n without consecutive vowels

Tags: recurrence-relations

Someone asked almost the [same question recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734764/recurrence-relation-to-calculate-the-number-of-strings-of-n-characters-that-do), but I'm having a ton of trouble trying to calculate the rest of the problem.

Comment: Can you please state clearly what your question is rather than linking to another question?

Answer (score 0):

You know the initial values $a_1=5$ and $b_1=21$. Let's write the given data in the form of vectors and matrices. You know that $\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 5\\21 & 21\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\b_{n}\end{pmatrix}$. Therefore, you need to calculate $\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\b_{n}\end{pmatrix}=A^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix}5\\21\end{pmatrix}$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 5\\21 & 21\end{pmatrix}$. Do you know how to calculate $A^{n-1}$ efficiently?

Comment: I'm used to setting up the problem going from W(1), W(2), W(3) and so on. I know that if n = 4 there's 412,776 possible strings so I've been trying to brute force the answer but I don't think I am calculating the sequence from W(4) down to W(1) correctly. It should just be W(n) = a * W(n-1) + b * W(n-2) right?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the number of strings of length $n$ without consecutive vowels $a_n$. We have $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 26$, and so on.

One gets a string without consecutive vowels by taking a string that ends in a vowel and adding any non-vowel, or one that ends in non-vowel and adding a vowel or a non-vowel. OK, distinguish those cases: call those that end in non-vowel $u_n$, those that end in vowel $v_n$. Then $a_n = u_n + v_n$, and:

- Make one ending in non-vowel: $u_{n + 1} = 21 (u_n + v_n)$
- Make one ending in a vowel: $v_{n + 1} = 5 u_n$

It is easier to solve directly from here. Define generating functions $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, and similarly $U(z)$ and $V(z)$. Multiply the recurrences by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize the resulting sums:
\begin{align}
\frac{U(z) - u_0}{z}
  &= 21 U(z) + 21 V(z) \\
\frac{V(z) - v_0}{z}
  &= 5 U(z) \\
A(z)
  &= U(z) + V(z)
\end{align}
With $u_1 = 0$, $v_0 = 0$, one gets:
\begin{align}
U(z)
  &= \frac{21 z}{1 - 21 z + 105 z^2} \\
V(z)
  &= \frac{1 - 21 z}{1 - 21 z + 105 z^2} \\
A(z)
  &= \frac{1}{1 - 21 z + 105 z^2}
\end{align}
Doing the above backwards you get that:
$$
a_{n + 2} = 21 a_{n + 1} - 105 a_n
$$
Add the initial values $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 26$.